# BFS Spanning Tree pseudocode question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

This is a pseudocode for finding a spanning tree in a simple connected graph G, from *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications* by Kenneth H. Rosen, in page 827, using breadth-first search:

> **procedure** BFS(G: connected graph with vertices v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, ... , v<sub>n</sub>)
> T := tree consisting only of vertex v<sub>1</sub>.
> L := empty list
> put v1 in the list L of unprocessed vertices
> **while** L is not empty
>      remove the first vertex, v, from L
>      **for** each neighbor w of v
>           **if** w is not in L and not in T **then**
>                add w to the end of the list L
>                add w and edge {v,w} to T

What I don't understand is, is it necessary to check if w is not in BOTH L and T? Doesn't it suffice to check just T? I have tried applying this algorithm to numerous examples but can't find a case where w is in L but not in T. (either it was both in L and T, or only in T). From what I understand, wouldn't any vertex in L always be in T because it is added to both L and T, and vertices in T remain unremoved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the algorithm preserves the invariant that $L$ is a subset of the vertex set of $T$. Although it turns out to be unnecessary in this case, avoiding having duplicates in the "todo" list is often important (to prevent a combinatorial explosion of repeated work on some graphs), so the author probably included it out of habit or to simplify analysis of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

Before the while loop we start with one vertex $v$ and it is in both $L$ and $T$.

We never remove a vertex from $T$ so even if a vertex has been removed from $L$, it is still in $T$. Therefore, if it is in neither $L$ nor $T$ then it is not in $T$.

If a vertex is in $L$ then it is in $T$ because every time we add an element to $L$ we add it to $T$.

Therefore, this algorithm works perfectly well by just checking if a neighbor is not in $T$.